# Nuxt package.json NODE_ENV Invalid setting

Tags: webpack, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a `Nuxt.js` project that needs to be released to different environments

package.json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRLsc.png)

```
"compile:dev-start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev nuxt build && cross-env NODE_ENV=dev nuxt start",
"compile:qafc-start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=qafc nuxt build && cross-env NODE_ENV=qafc nuxt start",
```

But the value obtained by `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not a dev or qafc value
But it is production. Is this what is the reason? How can I get dev or qafc?

Comment: post the node command you use to start the server

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem
The reason is that I can read this NODE_ENV value at build time, but when the project is started, it is changed to production. This may be done by nuxt.
So when you pack, you can make a decision.
What's your opinion?